# SQLAlchemy : Querying a database column using elements from a given array

Tags: python, sql, arrays, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a problem with writing a Query using SQL ALchemy, I am running in Python 3.6.
I need to filter the content of a column in my SQLite Database using parameters contained in an array. So far I have been using the following method to select elements from the database:

```
conn.execute(select([(mydatabase)]).where(mydatabase.c.filename == samplefile1 ))
```

Now however my program provides a list of possible files contained in an array:

```
files = [ filename1, filename2, filename3 ]
```

And I would like to create a query that automatically runs through the possible names provided in the array and selects them using a simple:

```
conn.execute(select([(mydatabase)]).where(or_(mydatabase.c.filename == filename1, mydatabase.c.filename == filename2 ... ect ))
```

Is there a way of automating this?? Or do I have to pass these all the time manualy? This is a problem as each time the program runs it will have a different number of possible names in the files array.

Can anyone help me how to figure this out? Is it possible to write this using a for loop?

Comment: mydatabase.c.filename.in_(files)

Comment: Is there any way this search can be made NOT CASE SENSITIVE????

Comment: Something like lower(table.filename).in_(files)